# wicked_pdf footer not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

I have these installed and using Mountain Lion:

- wicked_pdf (0.9.6)
- qt-4.8.4
- wkhtmltopdf 0.10.0 rc2

I installed qt and wkhtmltopdf using brew install --devel --build-patched-qt wkhtmltopdf

I am using Rails 3.2 and have these code in my controller:

```
render pdf: Time.now.to_i.to_s, 
       layout: false, 
       template: 'invoices/download', 
       disposition: 'attachment',
       page_size: 'A4',
       footer: {
                  left: Time.now.to_i.to_s, 
                  center: Time.now.to_i.to_s, 
                  right: Time.now.to_i.to_s
                }
```

The content is being generated fine, but no footer. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

At some stage this can be an issue with the way you've installed `wkhtmltopdf` as it may not generate the necessary footers. Also noticed your on OSx so I believe you would've downloaded wkhtmltopdf [here](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf.dmg&can=2&q=) and then cd to correct directory by doing something `cd /usr/local/bin && ln -s /Applications/wkhtmltopdf.app/Contents/MacOS/wkhtmltopdf wkhtmltopdf`.

I believe inside your respond block you should have something like:

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "#{DateTime.now.to_s}",
                :footer=> { left: Time.now.to_s, 
                            center: Time.now.to_s, 
                            right: Time.now.to_s
              }
```

Further to this is was a bit strange you were doing `Time.now.to_i.to_s` to from my experience this doesn't make sense and sure as this is not going to output what you want. Because:

**Time.now.to_i:** This returns the value of the time as an integer of seconds.

```
Time.now.to_i 
#=> "1270968656.89607"
```

**Time.now.to_s:** Returns value of time as a string.

```
Time.now.to_s 
#=> "2012-11-10 18:16:12 +0100"
```

When you are trying to do `Time.now.to_i.to_s` when this is executed it will get the time and execute the first method which is `to_i` and to illustrate what your output is [Imgur - Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fong5.png). Because from my understanding what you are trying to do is list the time convert it to an integer and then convert it to a string. There is no need for this just simply do `Time.now.to_s` that will do. As for your problem regarding the footer issue with `wicked_pdf` this can be down to your installation. As earlier mentioned take a look at the link supplied, also revise your setup and consider the suggested setup I've provided. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks for your response. I need a solution for my issue. I installed it via Homebrew.

The Time.now.to_i thing, that is a less worry. Just used it for my sample. And by the way, if you tried to run Time.now.to_i or any decimal or float to_i, you should not have a decimal value since it's should be integer.

Comment: @RodMedina So your problem is regarding the footer appearing. Have you tried setting your respond block as the following in my example? Also please ensure your setup of `wkhtmltopdf` is also correct.

Comment: @David, you saved me a lot of time. With your comment, I noticed that the footer appeared or not from server to server. I'll try to remove and reinstall this thing.

Comment: @MauricioMoraes glad to hear it helped :)